# Modify Crossfilter "Flights" example so one of graphs is not a group-by graph?

Tags: crossfilter

I'm trying to use the [Crossfilter example site](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) as a start for my desired graph, but am struggling with creating a non grouped graph that interacts with a grouped graph.

My data is a list of unique *employee* records:

```
employee,cnt
john,3
bill,15
fred,30
jill,6
...
```

I want one graph to show the *cnt* field grouped by value, analogous to the example's *Distance* graph. The next graph I want would have a bar for each *employee*, but instead of grouping them by *employee* value, I want the graph instead to simply show the *cnt* value.

Here's what I got going so far; however, this does group-by on both graphs:

```
// ...

var crossData = crossfilter(data),
    all = crossData.groupAll(),
    cnt = crossData.dimension(function(d) { return d.cnt; }),
    cnts = cnt.group(),
    emp = crossData.dimension(function(d) { return d.employee; }),
    emps = emp.group();

var charts = [  
  barChart()
      .dimension(cnt)
      .group(cnts)
    .x(d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 15])
      .rangeRound([0, 920])),

  barChart()
      .dimension(emp)
      .group(emps)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, 920])
      .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.employee; })))  
];

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your "emps" group sum by cnt, like this:

```
emps = emp.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.cnt; });
```

That will give you the sum of the cnt field for each employee. Since you only have one record per employee, you'll just get the value of the cnt field.